Is it acceptable to use "and which" to introduce a modifying clause—or is the “which” redundant and/or incorrect?
I’ve often written sentences of the form

(X happened) in a classroom that was led by a teacher and which featured real students.

A co-worker insists it should be

(X happened) in a classroom that was led by a teacher and featured real students.

The intent of my sentence is to emphasise that (a) It was a classroom that was led by a teacher, and (b) it was a classroom that featured real students.
Is one of these versions incorrect?

In any case, don’t mix your thats and whichs. Then decide if you want to repeat that for emphasis (in a classroom that was led by a teacher and that featured real students) or leave it out for brevity (in a classroom that was led by a teacher and featured real students).

@TinfoilHat There’s no pressing need to avoid using both for the same function in the same sentence. That’s because it can sometimes sound better to vary them. For example, it does here, at least to my own ear: “This is a good example of the traps that he most unwittingly laid, and which I cannot hope to have evaded in more significant matters than this.” If you look around in print, as I have just now done, I’m sure you can find many other similar examples besides that one alone. // I know you can give good answers in the answer box. :)

As is often the case, the actual example is hard to judge for better style because of a more significant incongruity. A classroom featuring real students?

@EdwinAshworth I guess you've been retired too long. They've replaced the students with AI these days. :)

@EdwinAshworth Oh, this was from a news page about the would-be assassin. CBS News: “BlackRock filmed the spot ... in a classroom led by a real teacher and which featured real students.”

@TinFoilHat Like tchrist says, “that ..., and which...” sounds better than “that ... and that...” — And that’s really the reason I tend to use the “which.” Still, your comment clarifies that the “and which” bit isn’t incorrect.

@RamLastname The quote in your comment doesn't match that in the original question. Which was it?

@StuartF The quote was “BlackRock filmed the spot ... in a classroom led by a real teacher and which featured real students.” My example modified that to “(X happened) in a classroom that was led by a teacher and which featured real students.” → Yes, the question changes a little because a that and a which in a sentence as short as this might become the focus of attention. So well, the original question remains: Is “...and which...” as a modifier correct—but there’s an additional question: The question of a that and a which (or two that s).
